# Proving that $\int_0^1 \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial z}(t,z)\right)^2\mathrm{d}z \geq 2 \int_0^1 T^2(t,z)\mathrm{d}z$

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, integral-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

**Exercise :**

> Assume that $T$ satisfies the equation $T_t(t,z) = aT_{zz}(t,z)$ for $t>0, z \in (0,1)$ and $a > 0$ a constant. Moreover, suppose that $T(0,z) = T_0(z)$ for $z \in [0,1]$, where $T_0 : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ and that $T(t,0) = T(t,1) = 0$.
>
> Show that :
> $$\int_0^1 \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial z}(t,z)\right)^2\mathrm{d}z \geq 2 \int_0^1 T^2(t,z)\mathrm{d}z$$

**Attempt-thoughts :**

Since we have the boundary conditions $T(t,0) = T(t,1) = 0$ for the problem and our integrations are over the interval $[0,1]$, we can "see" the given inequality as a norm-2 inequality and use the Wirtinger inequality which gives us a weaker lower bound than the one desired though, as it would be :
$$\text{Wirtinger :} \;\|T_z\|_2^2 \geq \pi^2\|T\|_2^2 \Leftrightarrow \int_0^1 \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial z}(t,z)\right)^2\mathrm{d}z \geq \pi^2 \int_0^1 T^2(t,z)\mathrm{d}z$$

So, that intuition falls short.

**Important :** Another thought, since its often carried out in such cases (and also a hint given by our professor) is that the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality shall be used. I cannot see how though.

Finally, I have previously proven via substitution from the PDE and integration by parts, that :

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \int_0^1 T^2(t,z)\mathrm{d}z = -2a\int_0^1 \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial z}(t,z)\right)^2\mathrm{d}z $$

I don't know if that can be of any help.

**Any hints or elaborations will be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: I can’t see why Wirtinger fails, if it proves a stronger lower bound...

Comment: @Mindlack $$\pi^2 \int_0^1 T^2(t,z)\mathrm{d}z  > 2 \int_0^1 T^2(t,z)\mathrm{d}z$$

Comment: Indeed, but that’s the good way, isn’t it? $\|T_z\|^2 \geq \pi^2 \|T\|^2 > 2\|T\|^2$ .

Comment: @Mindlack No, you're mistaken. $\|T_z\|_2^2 > 2\|T\|_2^2$ loses the $\leq$ implication. Also, Cauchy-Schwarz is probably hinter for a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work for $f=T(t,\cdot)$ or am I completely mistaken?

Let $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be any $\mathscr{C}^1$ function st $f(0)=f(1)=0$. 
For $0 \leq x \leq 0.5$, $f^2(x)=\left(\int_0^x{f’}\right)^2 \leq x\int_0^{1/2}{f’^2}$ by Cauchy-Schwarz.

Similarly, if $0.5 \leq x \leq 1$, $f^2(x) \leq (1-x)\int_{0.5}^1{f’^2}$.

Thus $\int_0^1{f^2} \leq \int_0^1{f’^2}\int_0^{1/2}{xdx}=\frac{1}{8}\int_0^1{f’^2} \leq \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1{f’^2}$.

Comment: It probably works and it's pretty neat too but since we are involving partial differentiation I am trying to decide if there will be any problems with variable-related "constants".